# How to get client origin in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

i have multiple domains for example  `https://www.ilajobs.com` `levelcoding.com`

when i try to get client origin like this

```
getOrigin() {
   this.origin = window.location.origin;
},
```

expected result

```
ilajobs
```

what i am getting

```
https://www.ilajobs.com
```

how to remove TLD from origin

Comment: please share what you have tried out so far

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry i have updated please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try host property because origin one returns the domain name and the protocol  :

```
getOrigin() {
   let host=window.location.host
   this.origin =host.slice(0,host.lastIndexOf('.'));
},
```

this remove the `.com` or `.origin` (TLD)

Comment: i am testing in `http://localhost:3000` result output `localhost:300` is this fine because i cant test in production server

Comment: for `http://localhost:3000` you know that the host is localhost

Comment: start with `let host=window.location.host.split(':')[0]` - then check if there's a `.` in host, if so then slice it, otherwise don't slice it